# Getting a specific child value from nodes only in which user's UID is present

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am working on a group chat application, and I'm running into trouble trying to make a specific query to Firebase DB.

I need to get all of the profile pictures of users in a room. But only the rooms that the current user is a part of.

```
private func observeRooms() {

    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let groupRef = databaseRef.child("groups")

    guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {return}
    let queryRef = groupRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "participants/\(uid)").queryEqual(toValue: nil)

    queryRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

        let roomDict = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
        print("roomDict: \(roomDict)")
        let id = snapshot.key

        let avatar = roomDict["profilePicture"] as! String
    })
}
```

Obviously setting `queryEqual(toValue: nil)` returns all the rooms that the current user is NOT a part of - the opposite of what I need. I know the inverse will be to check `queryEqual(toValue: true)`, but the `: true` is not showing up in the database.

This is how I add a node to "groups" in Firebase:

```
        // Start group node for new room
        let groupRef: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("groups")
        let roomID = newRoomRef.key
        let groupRoomRef = groupRef.child(roomID)
        let groupDict = ["roomName" : roomName, "participants": [uid : true]] as [String : Any]
        groupRoomRef.setValue(groupDict)
```

And this is how the data structure ends up:

```
"groups" : {
  "-KkGzZ7frbnXmImt0JpV" : {
    "participants" : {
      "tzfHgGKWLEPzPU9GvkO4XE1QKy53" : {
        "gender" : "male",
        "handle" : "Testing",
        "name" : "Test User",
        "profilePicture" : "https://graph.facebook.com/*removed*/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1",
        "status" : "F8B016"
      }
    },
    "roomName" : "Test Room"
  },
```

How can I properly the `profilePicture` values for all users in a room, only for the groups that the current user's UID is a participant of?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. When using `queryEqual` your query needs to match the value actually present in the database. Unfortunately that gets complicated when the values you're querying against are complex objects. In fact I'm not sure the function will work even if you did match the entire object value. The issue here is that you're trying to look up objects by the presence of a **child key**, instead of actually sorting by or matching their values. That doesn't quite fit the use case of any of the `orderBy` methods.

There are a few ways to work around this, ordered by effort.

**First**, you could take advantage of the [sort order](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#data-order) to get only those who have *some object* with the name of the UID. Since Firebase sorts nulls first, then primitives, and finally objects, you should be able to order by child and **start at** `true` (or any primitive) to get all object instances with that key (assuming, of course, you're not storing `UID: true` anywhere).

`groupRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "participants/\(uid)").queryStartingAtValue(true)`

**Second**, duplicate the UID as a key inside the object with the value `true` so that you can sort on it directly. Notice the extra step in the query.

```
"groups" : {
  "-KkGzZ7frbnXmImt0JpV" : {
    "participants" : {
      "tzfHgGKWLEPzPU9GvkO4XE1QKy53" : {
        "tzfHgGKWLEPzPU9GvkO4XE1QKy53" : true,
        ...
```

`groupRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "participants/\(uid)/\(uid)").queryEqual(toValue: true)`

**Finally, and this is what I recommend**, reconsider your data structure. You're nesting a lot of data inside this collection of collections that is going to make your queries and updates unwieldy. Firebase tends to work better when you [denormalize your data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure), preferring flat/shallow structures with some duplication of simple data. In your case, instead of storing the user's profile data inside of their group membership, you might have a collection of groups and another collection of users, with each group containing only a list of UIDs to its members **and vice versa**. The example in the documentation is a very similar case to yours involving membership in chat conversations. At that point your UIDs (and group IDs, if you're querying on users instead) will have a value of `true` so you can again use a simple value query.

```
"groups" : {
"-KkGzZ7frbnXmImt0JpV" : {
  "participants" : {
    "tzfHgGKWLEPzPU9GvkO4XE1QKy53" : true
    ...

"users" : {
"tzfHgGKWLEPzPU9GvkO4XE1QKy53" : {
  "groups" : {
    "-KkGzZ7frbnXmImt0JpV" : true
    ...
```

`groupRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "participants/\(uid)").queryEqual(toValue: true)`

Comment: Good answer, thanks I'll try these suggestions. I have 3 "parent" nodes in Firebase: 1. Users (used mainly for searching users by handle) 2. Rooms (holds each room's messages) and 3. Groups (Identical to Rooms, except with participant data, and minus the messages). I'm wondering though, I do set the groups node with `"participants": [uid : true]`... why isn't it showing up that way in Firebase? I set the rooms node the same way and the `: true` shows up there. Only difference is the rooms node doesn't hold any user data.

Comment: I'd have to see more of your code to give a clear answer but from your samples it looks like you must be overwriting the initial `true` value with the user profile data at some point. A node cannot store both a value _and_ children. This sounds like potentially a separate question.